# OPC DA client library for Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opc

I'm developing an iPhone application with a couple of features.

Now I need to connect to an OPC DA server but I don't want to implement OPC by my self. Does an Objective-C library even exists? or are there other possible solutions for my problem (maybe C or C++ libraries?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I guess you want to access OPC DA Server information from an iPhone/iPad ?

OPC DA is part of the classic OPC specification and based on Microsoft COM Technology, so this might not be so easy.

A solution could be to use an OPC UA Gateway to expose your OPC DA Server over OPC UA, then use a C/C++ SDK or write your own using OPC Foundation ANSI C Stack, to get an OPC UA Client running and accessing your information.

Guys from Unified Automation (https://www.unified-automation.com/) have done some great stuff that you might want to give a look.

Comment: I am not working for this company or have any link with them, I just tried some of their products...

Answer (score 0):

well i don't know if exist any library for Objective-C, check out in [OPC Foundation](http://www.opcfoundation.org/) or maybe you should think about develop an webapp instead a native app

Regards